# How to change systray icon text style set by Shell_NotifyIcon

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, system-tray

When you add an icon to the system tray on Windows via Shell_NotifyIcon() function you can set the text that is shown when the mouse hovers over the icon.

```
NOTIFYICONDATA  systray_icon;
systray_icon.cbSize = sizeof(NOTIFYICONDATA);
systray_icon.uFlags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP;
...
_tcscpy_s(systray_icon.szTip, TEXT("Icon text..."));
Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, &systray_icon);
```

The question is: **is it possible to change style of this text(set it bold/italic, change color)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This is not set per icon; it's set per the system.

What you could do instead (though it's a lot more work) is to open your own little window over the icon, and control it yourself. You can do whatever you want in that case, of course - but you need to take care of things such as positioning of the window (just think about the fact that the entire task bar can be positioned on the right/top/left sides of the desktop, and not only on the bottom.

Comment: Ty. That is what i was expecting, but yet was hoping that there was a way to handle this.

Comment: You can use [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378426.aspx) to get the screen coordinates of your tray icon.

Comment: True. But then you need to figure out where it is on the screen (top right? bottom left? bottom right? and if it's bottom right, is the task bar horizontal or vertical), then you need to position your window in a way that will point at your icon. If you add a little arrow (like a chat window), it becomes even more difficult. Been there, done that. Not trivial.